# Given this joint probability table, how can I find this particular conditional(?) probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that in an electronic display sign in the Springfield Mall, there are three light bulbs in the first row and four light bulbs in the second row. Let $X$ denote the number of bulbs in the first that will be burned out at a specified time $t$, and let $Y$ denote the number of bulbs in the second row that will be burned out at the same time $t$. Suppose that the joint probability distribution function of $X$ (rows) and $Y$ (columns) is as specified in the following table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|cccc|}\hline
&&&&Y&&\\
\hline
&&0&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
&0&0.08&0.07&0.06&0.01&0.01\\
X&1&0.06&0.10&0.12&0.05&0.02\\
&2&0.05&0.06&0.09&0.04&0.03\\
&3&0.02&0.03&0.03&0.03&0.04\\
\hline\end{array}

The first three questions have been fairly straight forward:

> 1. Probability that less than two bulbs burned out in each of the two rows.
>
> $$0.08+0.07+0.1+0.06 = 0.31$$
>
> 2. Probability that the same number of bulbs burned out in both rows.
>
> $$0.08+0.1+0.09+0.03 = 0.3$$
>
> 3. Probability that more bulbs burned out in the first row than in the second row.
>
> $$0.06+0.05+0.02+0.06+0.03 = 0.22$$

**Less simple are the following**

> 4. Probability that one bulb burned out in the second row, given that two bulbs burned out in the first row.
> 5. Probability that less than two bulbs burned out in the second row, given that less than two bulbs burned out in the first row.

I assume given the methodology to either, I could solve the other.

Comment: Have a read of [this part of the wikipedia page on Baye's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem). Might be helpful

Comment: @lioness99a Is it really just a simple Bayes theorem problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it struck me as a good place to start

Comment: Also, I think you've missed off a $0.03$ from part $3$ ($X=3$, $Y=2$)

Comment: @lioness99a Thank you. So If I carry through the Bayes Theorem, my answer to 4 is .6

Comment: No, it is $P(Y=1|X=2)=\frac{P(X=2\cap Y=1)}{P(X=2)}=\frac{0.06}{0.05+0.06+0.09+0.04+0.03}$

Comment: @lioness99a: There is no `Baye's Theorem`. The man's name is `Bayes`, so the common usage is `Bayes' Theorem`.

Comment: @BruceET My apologies, that was a typo